# linq: find exact match of string in attribute value

Tags: string, linq, search

My xml file has the element MO:

`<MO name="xxxx-1000"/>`

I can find the the value of attribute "name" from MO by:

`string searchString;`

`doc.Root.Elements(ns + "MO").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Contains(searchString)`

But if the searchString = 1 or 10 or 100 it also finds 1000. It should not find anything as my desired output.

How can I find the exact match in this case?

Comment: i will re-write the question. what i meant it does not work because i don't want to find 1000 if i am looking for 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find only exact matches, is `-` always the delimiter?

Then you could use:

```
var query = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "MO")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Split('-').Last() == searchString);
```

Of course you could improvove it it's not always a number(f.e. `... .Equals(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`).

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and some improvements that matched the actual xml file, as some attributes' values are not always "xxxx" and delimiter is not always in the same position, did add another "for loop" iteration to get the desired results and it works! Thanks Tim... :)